# Angular using $index and $invalid in a ng-class expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm using an ng-repeat directive to generate a set of forms. 
I've managed to give unique names to each of the input fields using `$index`.

```
<input  ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.firstName-$index.$invalid }"
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="passenger.firstName"
    id="firstNameId-{{$index}}"
    name="firstName-{{$index}}"
    required
    >
```

But, I could not get the ng-class expression to work with both the $index and $invalid statements working together.

What should be done in order to get,
`ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.firstName-$index.$invalid }"`
to work?

Plunker is provided [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WuvNA59f8MgU5yNQgfeb?p=preview)

Comment: ca you use this  `ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.firstName-{{$index}}.$invalid }"`

Comment: That seems to partially work. Now on inspecting the element, it shows `ng-class="firstName-0.$invalid"` But it still does not change when the input is invalid.

Comment: provide your code on Plunker

Comment: An identifier like `firstName-1` is not valid in Javascript. Either use the `[...]` notation: `ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.['firstName-' + $index].$invalid }"` or use an underscore instead of the dash: `<input name="firstName_{{$index}}">` and `ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.firstName_$index.$invalid }"`.

Comment: @UR - I've created the uploaded the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WuvNA59f8MgU5yNQgfeb?p=preview)

Comment: @UR Please note I've just made an adjustment to the plunker to add the form.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I've tried the square brackets notation without no success. I've tried swapping out the dash with the underscore earlier. Which didn't work. I'll try that again.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I've replaced the dash with an underscore in this (plunker)[http://plnkr.co/edit/ha1aSKgS5RAkwITIyzEU?p=preview]. But it still acts the same as before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just removed the dash all together from the input name, it is now working as intended

```
<form name='userForm'>
  <div ng-repeat="person in people">
    <input ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.firstName{{$index}}.$invalid }" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="passenger.firstName" id="firstName{{$index}}" name="firstName{{$index}}" required />
  </div>
</form>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/efLlNT3pUVBmENik61gU?p=preview

Comment: It works! Also, I got it working by replacing the dash with an underscore.

Comment: Could you also please clarify why `$index` doesn't work without the curly braces?